# Authentication not lasting for the user session

Tags: security, formsauthentication

My website is constantly forcing me back to the logon page (authentication issue) in between requests.

My local website works just fine and is the same exact code. There is no authentication issue...

I've been scouring over the web and tearing my hair out all day on this issue trying different things as suggested, etc.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on and how I can rectify it?

```
[HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl) 
        { 
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            { 
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) 
                { 
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe); 

                    Session["Email"] = model.Email; 

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") 
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) 
                    { 
                        return Redirect(returnUrl); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
                    } 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", YeagerTechResources.Resources.AcctUserNamePswdInCorrect); 
                } 
            } 

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form 
            return View(model); 
}
```

Below, is the following image of the cookies available immediately after I log onto the production site. Note that no cookies are listed.

Cookie Information - http://yeagertech.com/

Now, if you look at the same info executing the same code for my development site, you see the following. This is driving me nuts and have wasted a whole day on this. I'd apprecaite anyone with some help!

Cookie Information - http://localhost:4514/

NAME

proxy

VALUE

http://localhost:62613/proxy/0/

DOMAIN

localhost

PATH

/

EXPIRES

2/12/2012 8:21:16 PM

Note that after several reqeusts, it goes back to the logon page --- only on the production site and not on my local site.

It seems like the cookie on the production site doesn't have a long enough shelf life before it needs to go back to the log on page.

I basically want the cookie to persist at least for the user session.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks again....

I needed to configure the settings in IIS associated with this website which I did and got the following error:

"Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server. Please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above"

Upon receiving this error, I found that Session State needs to be enabled on SQL Server, so, I tried running the InstallSqlState.SQL file (located in the Microsoft.Net version folder on my local PC).

After trying to run the script, it fails (with the below error), because there is no "msdb" database on my hosted database server within the SystemDatabases folder.

"CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. If the job does not exist, an error from msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job is expected. Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_delete_job, Line 1 The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_delete_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Database 'ASPState' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."

So, unless there is an msdb database on my hosted database (all I have is master and tempdb), it is impossible for me to set up session state on my sql server.

I would like to know how to proceed from here.

btw, I find it very unlikely that even if it was enabled, that this would solve the issue. My situation does not fit into any of the 3 bullet points you initially outlined.

It's a small db with hardly any records in it. I'm simply testing it out with my website to ensure it's working OK before I start to add records to it. There is no time lapse either.

I go to a couple of pages fine, and then all of a sudden, back to the logon page...

If my local machine is working fine, it defintley has to do with something that I need to set because I'm running off of your servers.

I would appreciate any help....

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this type of issue but not in MVC....issue was that FormsAuthentication Ticket expires within 1 minute on hosting server.......

the problem might be that your worker process recycling constantly that will result in ticket expiration or session ending automatically....what you can do is talk to your hosting  provider and up your Private Memory Limit or Virtual Memory Limit of your application pool
or you can ask them for machine key elements which is used to encrypt and decrypt the ticket may be that will solve this issue

I am also in constantly touch with my hosting provider but their product development team taking too much time to resolve the issue

Comment: Changing the session from InProc to SQLServer server worked for me.